# Python Pandas - Assign string based on whether a value appears across multiple days

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({"Value": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "D", "A", "B"],
                "Day": ["2023-06-12", "2023-06-12", "2023-06-12", "2023-06-12", "2023-06-13", "2023-06-13", "2023-06-14", "2023-06-14"]  
               })
```

```
Day        | Value
------------------
2023-06-12 | A
2023-06-12 | B
2023-06-12 | C
2023-06-12 | D
2023-06-13 | A
2023-06-13 | D
2023-06-14 | A
2023-06-14 | B
```

Which leads to the following conditions:

A: appears 3 days in a row -> Trend

B: appears twice but not on consecutive days -> Sporadic

C: appears only once -> Anomaly

D: appears 2 days in a row -> Becoming a trend

I ultimately want a dataframe that looks like this

```
Day        | Value | Trend Type
--------------------------------
2023-06-12 | A     | Trend
2023-06-12 | B     | Sporadic
2023-06-12 | C     | Anomaly
2023-06-12 | D     | Becoming a trend
2023-06-13 | A     | Trend
2023-06-13 | D     | Becoming a trend
2023-06-14 | A     | Trend
2023-06-14 | B     | Sporadic
```

I've tried using a groupby and calculating the difference between the days and summing for appearance for each value but that's not really getting me close, and I'm having particular trouble thinking how to approach the 'Sporadic' trend type. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a custom function here:

```
df['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Day'])

def mapper(x):
    m = x.diff().eq('1day')
    max_consec = m.groupby((~m).cumsum()).sum().max()
    if max_consec >= 2:
        return 'Trend'
    elif max_consec >= 1:
        return 'Becoming a trend'
    elif len(x)>=2:
        return 'Sporadic'
    elif len(x)==1:
        return 'Anomaly'
    return 'Other'

df['Trend Type'] = df.groupby('Value')['Day'].transform(mapper)
```

Output:

```
  Value        Day        Trend Type
0     A 2023-06-12             Trend
1     B 2023-06-12          Sporadic
2     C 2023-06-12           Anomaly
3     D 2023-06-12  Becoming a trend
4     A 2023-06-13             Trend
5     D 2023-06-13  Becoming a trend
6     A 2023-06-14             Trend
7     B 2023-06-14          Sporadic
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse dates for ease:

```py
df['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Day'])
```

Compute then the time between values (we need to use .apply to keep the Value column). I used also `fillna` to have values of the future in the present (diff will always return NaN for the first value):

```py
>>> df = df.groupby('Value').apply(lambda x: x.diff().fillna(method='bfill'))
           Day
Value         
A     0 1 days
      4 1 days
      6 1 days
B     1 2 days
      7 2 days
C     2    NaT
D     3 1 days
      5 1 days
```

This will create a multindex dataframe, but we will reset to normal state now:

```py
>>> df = df.reset_index('Value').sort_index()
  Value    Day
0     A    NaT
1     B    NaT
2     C    NaT
3     D    NaT
4     A 1 days
5     D 1 days
6     A 1 days
7     B 2 days
```

Now is just a matter of replacing values:

```py
>>> df['Day'].replace(pd.Timedelta(days=1), 'Trend')
0              Trend
1    2 days 00:00:00
2                NaT
3              Trend
4              Trend
5              Trend
6              Trend
7    2 days 00:00:00
Name: Day, dtype: object
```

And so on with all the values that you want to